# Is there a way to connect xamarin login page to my website in Webview?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, mobile-website

I made a login form page in xamarin crossplatform then i want the value of entry like user and password will connect to my website in webview

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Follow this article [Customizing a WebView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview) to know how to use the `WebView` in scenarios where you want to return json information ( for example: in your case you want to return the user id of the logged in user and other data maybe).

Comment: yes i hope i can do this.. because this is quitely hard

Comment: so if i do this, i will make A JavaScript code thar injects C# ?

Comment: Yes, once the user press login and after your validate the credentials, you can initiate a callback function from js which it fires in the xamarin c# code, you can pass user id or a token